# IllegallStateException in onStartCommand()

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, android-broadcastreceiver

I have a broadcast receiver which starts service with some simple calculations. It works as expected on all devices I tested, but some of devices crashed (I have none of them to catch manually) and here's stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs (ActivityThread.java:3045)

at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200 (ActivityThread.java:157)

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1454)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)

at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5551)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:730)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:620)


Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 

at com.mypackage.name.tools.WorkerService.onStartCommand (WorkerService.kt)

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs (ActivityThread.java:3028)
```

And here's Service's method:

```
 override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    println("start command")
    init()
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
}
```

Any thoughts on where the problem can be? I also start foreground service in onCreate but it helped with only some number of devices.

```
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    startForegroundInside()
}

  private fun startForegroundInside() {
    if (App.isOreo()) {
        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, createNotificationChannel())
        startForeground(101, notificationBuilder.build())
    } else {
        startForeground(101, Notification())
    }

}

private fun init() {
//calc
//...
restartAlarm()
stopSelf()
}
```

Comment: Put the whole code snippet of service.

Comment: @KrupalShah I did add, many it would help you to give me some advices

Comment: Did you find out why the error was caused? I get the same error on some devices.

Comment: @kksal switching to Java could solve my problem, but this application was removed from the store, so really don't know neither the solution, nor the reason